# Javascript Containing objects in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've got this code for creating a dialog box in photoshop which contains 4 panels. It worked fine when I wasn't running it through a loop, but the code was bulky and ugly. now I get an error saying "panel1 is undefined". Can I not put objects in arrays like this?

```
// create a dialog window, dig.panel = dialog panel
var dig = new Window('dialog', 'Poster Interface - Choose 4 Images', [550, 120, 1150, 800]);

//define variables for panel dimensions
var digX = 100;
var digY = 50;
var digWidth = 510;
var digHeight = 140;
var digUp = 110;

var panels = [
    [panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4]
];
var labels = [
    [label1, label2, label3, label4]
];
var texts = [
    [t1, t2, t3, t4]
];
var buttons = [
    [bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4]
];


//create panels for the image components
//first loop for panel dimensions multiply by x
// nested loop for contents using i

for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    dig.panels[x] = dig.add('panel', [digX, digY + (digUp * x), digWidth, digHeight + (digUp * x)], 'Image ' + (x + 1) + ':');
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        dig.panels[i].labels[i] = dig.panels[i].add('statictext', [20, 20, 120, 40], 'Choose Image' + (i + 1) + ':');
        dig.panels[i].texts[i] = dig.panels[i].add('edittext', [125, 20, 325, 40], 'image' + (i + 1) + '.jpg');
        dig.panels[i].buttons[i] = dig.panels[i].add('button', [330, 20, 380, 40], 'Open');
    }
}
```

This is wrecking my head. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You have `var panels = [[panel1,panel2,panel3,panel4]];` but where is `panel1` coming from?

Comment: Missing some quotations there maybe?

Comment: i think im starting to realise. I'm declaring but not initialising?

Comment: panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4 are undefined...

Answer (score 0):

To create an array of variables in javascript:

```
var var1 = "value";
var var2 = "value";

var array = [var1,var2];
```

You are creating an array, with an array inside it, with variables inside the inner array.

```
var panels = [
[panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4]
];
```

You have not displayed to us that those variables have been defined.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/rfhq01L3/

with the following code:

```
var var1 = "value";
var var2 = "value";

var array = [var1,var2];
var array2 = [[var1,var2]];

console.log(array);
console.log(array2);
```

Go there and look at the console. You will notice the length of array2 is only 1 while the length of array is 2. So, you need to define your variables, then build the array in the format you want it (do you really want an array of arrays?) Then you can loop and add properties.

Also, an object means something in javascript. In javascript it is typical to see an object created using object literal syntax.

```
Object = {
property1 : "property",
property2: "property"
}
```

So when you asked if you could have an array of object, yes you can. However you have to create those objects and their properties first.

Comment: ok thanks man, i reckon ill just go back to the way it was without the loop.

Comment: Don't give up! You can do it! :-D Try some more, then come back and ask specific questions!